# program to print the frequency of elements in react but getting error "Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
for (counter = 0;counter < actualLength;counter++){
getCharacter = this.sentence.charAt(counter);
  if (getCharacter>='a' && getCharacter <'z')
    noOfCount = noOfCountsOfEachCharacter[getCharacter];
    noOfCountsOfEachCharacter[getCharacter] = noOfCount ? noOfCount + 1 : 1;
}
document.write('<table border="1" align-items="center">')
for (counter = 0; counter < 26; counter++){
var sortChar = lowerAlph[counter];
document.writeln("<tr><td>" + sortChar + "</td>")
document.writeln("<td>" +noOfCountsOfEachCharacter[sortChar] + "</td></tr>")
}
```

Getting the value of sentence through an API which is working fine but getting an error as "Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined".
Stuck here for so long thanks for solving in advance.

Comment: Probably because `this.sentence` is undefined.

Comment: Is this a react component by the way?

Comment: thanks but this.sentence is defined and by just printing the value of this.state.sentence I'm getting write value. anything else

Comment: yes, shall I share the full code. Actually I have just started with react and don't know much and also struggling with errors since morning but couldn't overcome this error

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a typo.

You should access state variables like this

```
this.state.sentence.charAt(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is inside a React class component. If that's the case, you may be running this code before `this.sentence` has any data on it. Like you said, its populated from an API, so you need to make sure to run that code after it's populated.

Another issue is that you're accessing the value as a class variable and not a state variable, it should be

`this.state.sentence`.

Comment: Thanks, Marquez it really helped